# Clicking on button in form doesnt do anything

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

This is a trial login screen using NodeJS.. The code is for a login screen but the submit button doesn't do anything. What does this code missing? The button doessnt direct to the dashboard screen i had created.

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> <%=title%> </title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
</head>
<body><h1> LMS</h1>
    <form>
        <div class="text-center center-div "id="login">
            <div class="container w-25 py-5">
                <div class="title pb-5">
                    <h2 class="font-weight-bold">Login System</h2>
                    <span> Login for the existing user</span>
                </div>
                <form action="/route/login" method="post" class="pt-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="email" placeholder="email">
                        <small class="form-text text-muted text-left">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="password" placeholder="password">
                    </div>
                
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success rounded-pill">Submit</button>
                </form>
                
            </div>          
        </div>
                
        
  
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

***ROUTER JS***

```
var express=require("express");

var router=express.Router();

const credentials={email:"rnwit@gmail.com",password:"Chennai@123"}
//login
router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    if (req.body.email==credentials.email && req.body.password==credentials.password){
        req.session.user=req.body.email;
        res.redirect("/route/dashboard");
        //res.end("login successs");
    }else{
        res.end("Imvalid username and password");
    }
});

//dashboard
router.get('/dashboard',(req,res)=>{
    if(req.session.user){
        res.render('/dashboard',{user:req.session.user})
    }else{
        res.send('Unauthorised user')
    }
})
module.exports=router;
```

***APP JS***

```
const express = require("express");
const path=require("path");
const bodyparser=require("body-parser");
const session=require("express-session");
const {v4:uuidv4}=require("uuid");

const router=require("./router");


const app = express();


const port=process.env.PORT ||8080;


app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.set('view engine','ejs');


//LOAD STATIC ASSETS
app.use('/static',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.use('/assets',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'assets','images')));

app.use(session({
  secret:uuidv4(),
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialized:true
}));

app.use('/route',router);

//ROUTE
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('base',{'title':'Login System'})
})


app.listen(port,()=>{'Listening on port 3000'});
```

Could anyone check and say what is missing here and whay the form submit button would not work?

Comment: Nested [forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#technical_summary) are not allowed. Because of the invalid HTML, browsers strip the inner form and include all the form elements in the outer form, which in your case doesn't have `action` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Teemu commented,***(Nested forms are not allowed. Because of the invalid HTML, browsers strip the inner form and include all the form elements in the outer form, which in your case doesn't have action attribute. –
Teemu)*** when i removed the outer form, it worked. Thanks